# Google API dailyLimitExceededUnreg

Tags: php, api, curl, google-api

I'm using the Google URL shortener API in a PHP app. It has been working for months but now I am getting this error:

```
[errors] => Array (
   [0] => stdClass Object (
      [domain] => usageLimits
      [reason] => dailyLimitExceededUnreg
      [message] => Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.
      [extendedHelp] => https://code.google.com/apis/console
    )
)
[code] => 403
[message] => Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.
```

I'm using the server key from the developer console, I regenerated the key and even deleted the server access key section and re-added it but I keep getting the same auth error.

```
$query_array = json_encode( array( "longUrl" => $data['long_url'], 'key' => 'AIza-Key' ) ); 

$curl = curl_init( 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url' );

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Content-Type: application/json' ) );

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query( $query_array ) ) ;             

curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

$short_url = json_decode( curl_exec( $curl ) );

$header = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT );

curl_close( $curl );

print_r( $short_url ) ; // shows above error
```

This API shouldn't be that hard, just add the server key in the URL string, but I'm not seeing the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: You should give feedback to the people that took the time to answer you (and accept it if the proposed solution worked for you)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are adding the `key` to the POST body instead of as a URL query string. Change the code to this:

```
$query_array = json_encode( array( "longUrl" => $data['long_url'] ) ); 

$curl = curl_init( 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=AIza-Key' );
```

Comment: The [docs state](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started#APIKey) "After you have an API key, your application can append the query parameter `key=yourAPIKey` to all request URLs." and `$query_array` isn't actually used for query params, but for the POST body.

Comment: Ok, I guessed based on the Python API, where you put everything together in the same array/dictionary. I'll delete the comment.