# Google Drive API - dailyLimitExceededUnreg

Tags: php, api, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm using the "google-api-php-client-2.4.0" class to interact with Google Drive APIs.

I followed all the authentication indications reported online but the system gives me the following error:

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URl7B.png)

This is a code:

```
$this->google_client = new Google_Client();
    $this->google_client->setAuthConfigFile($this->json_file_auth);
    $this->google_client->setScopes(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_FILE);
    $this->google_client->setScopes(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA);
    $this->google_client->setRedirectUri($this->redirectURI);
    $this->google_client->setClientId($this->id_client);
    $this->google_client->setClientSecret($this->secret_client);
if(!isset($_GET['code']){
    $auth = $this->google_client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
    $this->google_client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $accessToken = $this->google_client->getAccessToken();
    $drive_google = new Google_Service_Drive($this->google_client);

    $files = $drive_google->files->listFiles();

    echo json_encode($files);
```

Please, Who can help me?

Comment: The API response is actually telling you what the problem is and how to solve it. Did you read that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google API dailyLimitExceededUnreg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29593836/google-api-dailylimitexceededunreg). You have to use your API key (see: https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158862?hl=en)